# P-Norm and differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Let ($\mathbb{R}^n$,$|.|_p$)  the normed space

with $\left | x \right |_{p}=(|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$ the p-norm  $p>1$

let $\gamma:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ be a rectifiable curve parametrised by arc lenght

it's clear that a lot of thnigs change from the natural euclidean geometry  (unit disk , the lenght ...)

my Question Question are :
1_ how we define that two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ are orthogonal in this case  ?

2_how can we define the curvature in this case ($k(t)=| \gamma^{}"(t)| _{p}$) ?

3_ in general what changes compared to euclidean geometry ? 
did  you know book or a lecture notes on differential Geometry treat this case of non euclidean geometry ?

Comment: These norms are not induced by an inner product unless $p=2$, so I would not expect that there is a natural notion of angles (and hence orthogonality) in general. I do not know much about this otherwise though, so I might be wrong.

Comment: yes , and thes is why a posted the question, in the euclidean case thats comes from the inner product ... it's easy, but in this case i dont have any idea

Comment: $\|\cdot\|_p$ comes from an inner product **if and only if** $p=2$, so there's no way to talk about orthogonality...

Comment: Thank you @IvoTerek , if it's the case what do you think about Minkowski space , or finsler geometry

Comment: The scalar product in Minkowski space is not positive-definite, and so does not define a topology by itself. This is a general point of view in pseudo-Riemannian geometry: you start with a smooth manifold (which already has a topology), and then add the extra structure (the metric). Even if not positive-definite, you can talk about orthogonality if you have a scalar product. As a matter of fact, if vou have a bilinear map $B: V\times V \to \Bbb R$, you can even talk about left/right-ortogonality if $B$ is not symmetric or skew-symmetric.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Finsler geometry to comment on that, though.

Comment: Thank you @IvoTerek I think my Question is a particular case of Minkowski space .

Comment: Ah. When you said Minkowski space I was thinking of the product described in an orthonormal basis by ${\rm diag}(-1,+1,\ldots,+1)$. I recall people in Finsler geometry also use the term "Minkowski space" for something else. So I don't think my comment applies to your case.